# Spring Boot: disable DDL logging

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, logging

I set the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` as well as `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` in the test environment. I want to see SQL statements in the logs but only DML ones. Is it possible to disable DDL statements logging (`create table`, `drop table`, and etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. You can see for yourself by looking at `org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase#accept` which is the code that does the logging and afterwards executes the statement. The only thing you could do is set the log level to OFF initially and after boot, set it to DEBUG, but how you can do that, depends on the logging library that you use.

I think Spring uses SLF4J and logback so something like the following should work:

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
loggerContext.getLogger("org.hibernate.SQL").setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```